# htaccess - Redirect all URLs containing /THIS/something/ANDTHAT/

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My CMS is running into a loop often, because impossible URLs are generated. Those URLs have the format

```
www.xy.com/STRING1/something/STRING2/something
```

or

```
www.xy.com/something/STRING1/somethingother/anything/STRING2/something
```

I want to deny or block all URLs that contain STRING1 and STRING2 as segments.
Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with the accepted answer above, so I will post a correction...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?STRING1/.*/STRING2/ https://example.com/ [R=301]
```

Note: the `L` flag does not make any sense when you implement an external redirection. Also the matching is not really precise in the accepted answer...

In case you want to return an explicit http status (like 403) you can also do that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?STRING1/.*/STRING2/ - [R=403]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: arkascha, thank you very much. Would you mind to explain why you added ^/? to the RewriteRule?

Comment: That sequence makes the rule more portable. I wrote that this rule can be implemented in the real http server's host configuration _or_ in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"). That sequence does that trick, you need to keep in mind that a rewrite rule operates in a _relative_ path when implemented in a per-directory context, but on a normal, more robust _absolute_ path when implemented normally. That sequence takes care of handling the leading slash ("/"). This way the same rule can be used in _both_ situations without the need to alter anything. That pays out in the long run ;-)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! As it seems to me that your answer is more useful than the one I first accepted I shifted the accept to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this rewriting:

```
RewriteRule STRING1\/.*\/STRING2.* https://www.xy.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Heinz, this works! Do you perhaps have any idea how I could create an forbidden-error-code instead of a redirection?

Comment: Try `RewriteRule STRING1\/.*\/STRING2.* - [R=403,L]`. See
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77168/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-respond-with-403-forbidden-status-for-urls-that-conta. If this does not work open a new question.